# why should we use static fields in javascript if we can define fields on prototype object in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, static, prototype

when we use `class`(function) in javascript,Why should we use `static` fields on `class`(function),if we can define fields on `prototype` and all the instances can share it and modify it ,so that updated values will be visible to all instances.
Is there any performance improvement with static?In what cases we should make a field static?

Comment: _"The `static` keyword defines a static method for a class. **Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself.** These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects."_ ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static))

Comment: https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods

Comment: When we add property on function directly ..Function.propertyname